# Angular 2: component with more than one dependency

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

The following code:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'sitelink',
  properties: ['route: route, title: title, isHome: home, href: href']
})
@View({
  template: ''
})
export class SiteLink {
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() parentFrame: AppFrame, @Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() parentLink: SiteLink) {
  }
...
```

gives me the following error during the translation from TypeScript to JavaScript

```
at line 32, file app-frame.ts Argument of type 'typeof SiteLink' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
Component({
  selector: 'sitelink',
  properties: ['route: route, title: title, isHome: home, href: href']
})
at line 36, file app-frame.ts Argument of type 'typeof SiteLink' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
View({
  template: ''
})
```

Using only one constructor parameter works as expected. When removing the annotations from the parameter list, it does not work, too. After removing the `@Component` and `@View` annotations, the code compiles. So the error must be related to the `@Component` annotation.
Edit: Even if I replace the SiteLink parameter with another type (for example AppFrame), I get the same error.

I'm using alpha 36 and the latest d.ts files from the DefinitelyTyped repository.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible. In the constructor of `SiteLink` you are calling the class itself. Are you sure is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the parent "SiteLink" component.

Comment: The error is probably the same as this [problem](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3972). What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Yes, that may be the problem. I'm using the atom typescript plugin, which should use always the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jesse Good wrote, this is an issue with angular's d.ts file, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3972.

Replacing

```
  interface Type extends Function {
     new(args: any): any;
  }
```

with

```
  interface Type extends Function {
     new(...args): any;
  }
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to inject an instance of the class itself in the constructor by using a forward reference:

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => SiteLink)) siteLink) {
    this.name = nameService.getName();
}
```

See [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html) for more details.

Comment: That does not solve the issues. Even if I replace the SiteLink parameter with another type, I get the same error.